# Sending embed with server id, server name, member count when new server joined

Tags: discord.js

How should I go about running code to send a embed when a user joins a new guild?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the id from the specific channel you want to send it in somewhere and instead of console logging it you have to do something like `client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(embed)`

Answer (score 0):

You really need to specify your questions more, show what you are working on. StackOverflow **is not** coding service, but I'm feeling generous. Just remember this is example of the code that might not work for you, because I have no idea how your bot is set up.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
client.on("guildCreate", newguild => {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`NEW SERVER`)
    .addFields(
         {name: `SERVER`, value: newguild.name, inline: true},
         {name: `ID`, value: newguild.id, inline: true}
     );

     let supportserver = client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.id === 'support-server-id-here');
     supportserver.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === 'channel-id-here').send({embeds: [embed]});
});
```

Hopefully this will get you on the right track.